# What method does Paperclip use to clean up file name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Thoughtbot's Paperclip gem (v 3.2.1) will clean up filenames, replacing spaces and other special chars with underscores. I am reimporting data and need to check whether attachments have already been uploaded, but the original file name may not match the attached file name in Paperclip. What method does Paperclip use for the clean up?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer digging into the source code. It's a private instance method  Paperclip::Attachment#cleanup_filename . (Since this is a short lived (one off) import task I dont mind the (slight) risk of using an unpublished method.)

Thus my code looks something like this (Post has_many :attachments; Attachment has_attached_file :attached )

```
   if @post.attachments.present?
      cleaned_filename = @post.attachments.first.attached.send :cleanup_filename, filename 
      if @post.attachments.map(&:attached_file_name).include? cleaned_filename
        puts "already attached: #{filename}"
        return
      end
    end
    puts "attaching upload: #{filename}"
```

Comment: I found this to work for me:

```cleaned_filename = post.plan_pdf.send(:cleanup_filename, plan_pdf_name)```

where post was a new record OR a found record in the db. Thanks!

(This is not answering original question, just found a clean way to call the cleanup_filename through you)